# Is there a need for both caching 'this' and set its context in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, this

This code is from backbone.js, within the render method of a view. I noticed that the author had both cached 'this' to the var 'that', and also set the context to this. Is there any reason for both caching 'this' and also explicitly set the context? It seems to work with just one of them at works.

```
render: function () {
    var that = this;
    _.each(this.collection.models, function (item) {
        that.renderContact(item);
    }, this);
},
```

Comment: I'd guess this was just an oversight, or that two developers implemented their own solution to the same problem. But yes, this is overkill.

Comment: In this case, it serves no purpose and was probably just left behind after a refactor.

Comment: Yea looks like an oversight. I'm unsure of memory ramifications, but please correct me if I'm wrong, is Caching this to that in this instance will cause it to slow down (probably fractions of a nano second).

Comment: Also this marionette right?  Not backbone.  I don't think backbone have render predefined

Comment: @josephnvu I believe this is OP's render method, not Backbone source.

Answer (score 0):

this should be as simple as

```
this.collection.each(this.renderContact, this);
```

would accomplish what ever result that the code above trying to do

Comment: Do you still need to pass the context when calling `each` on a collection?

Comment: easier for you so that you are sure the called function are bind to the proper context